# Django message framework issue on C9 platform

Tags: django, message, django-1.9, c9.io

With the default configuration of Django in C9 the messages are not showed. I can see the cookies and the messages at there but I couldn't see the message at the page.
So I use the snipped code of [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/messages/#displaying-messages).
If I change the settings of Django to use the session storage and not the cookies it works:

```
MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.session.SessionStorage'
```

You can see my C9 repository by following this [link](https://ide.c9.io/wijan/formularicontacte).

So, my question is, why it doesn't work with the default storage with cookies?

Django version 1.9.0 final

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Testing for my own on local enviroment

I tested your code on my local environment and runs fine.

#### Testing for my own at C9

Digging into issue I realize than c9 is truncating your cookie at `$` symbol. To check it I just output some variable values at [this point](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.9.x/django/contrib/messages/storage/cookie.py#L71).

```
    data = self.request.COOKIES.get(self.cookie_name)
    print 'cookies->', self.request.COOKIES
    print 'data->', data
    messages = self._decode(data)
    print 'messages->', messages
```

Result was:

```
cookies-> {'messages': '00060c532edb4c08c778df44306c21e7aacfc15f$'}
data-> 00060c532edb4c08c778df44306c21e7aacfc15f$
messages-> None
--> 0
--> ['messages']
```

#### Confirming

To be sure that is a c9 issue I just wrote a little php program:

`Set cookie page`

```
<?php  
setcookie("c", "00060c532edb4c08c778df44306c21e7aacfc15f$also_this");   
?>
```

`Read cookie page`

```
Cookie value:    
<?php 

   echo $_COOKIE['c'];

?>
```

`Results`

```
Cookie value: 00060c532edb4c08c778df44306c21e7aacfc15f
```

### Answer

Then, it seems **your issue is with C9 platform rather than django framework**, looks like a bug, "feature" or constraint on that service: it truncates remaining cookie data after `$` character. [I ask them for an explanation](https://twitter.com/ctrl_alt_d/status/688374598845493248).